# Not able to find Console Output Parsing Section in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wanted to parse the console output using "Log Parser Plugin" . In the [documentation details](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) of configuration are provided. 
When I go to global configuration for my job I do not see any "Console Output Parsing" section where I 
can mention the path of the Parsing Rules files. Though I can see the Console Output (build log) Parsing section.

Because of this the plugin is not able to find the rules file path and I am getting this error:

> log-parser plugin ERROR: Cannot parse log: Can't read parsing rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Console Output Parsing* section under *Manage Jenkins* there is an *Add* button. Hit this and it will create a new rules section where you can input a description and path to the rules file.

If you do not see the *Add* button, try a different browser.

Rules added here will then be available to select in the job specific configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

1. Place the Parser Rule File (I've used `.txt` file) in the `JENKINS_HOME` location.
2. Configure the global configuration in hudson that link to the parser rule file with a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to get it to discover the rules file was to use the full path from the volume root for the rules file. Also, I had to re-save the jobs that were using the rules to get them to use the updated path.